# PHP-MySQLi OOP usage of fetch_object([ string $class_name = "stdClass" [, array $params ]])

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I've been banging my head against a pretty hard wall for the last few days trying to get to grips with **mysqli_result::fetch_object()**.

What I am trying to do is instantiate an array of Objects based on a pre-written class containing the methods I require for operation.
Simple enough? Sure, that is until I try to pass constructor parameters to each object.

Now passing parameters to the constructor of the class in a single instance works fine as demonstrated below:

```
<?php

 class classA {

  private $dbo;

  function __construct() {
   $this->dbo = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'user', 'pass', 'dbName', 3306);
  }

  public function createObject() {
   $stmt = $this->dbo->query("SELECT `column` FROM `table` WHERE `column` = 'value';");
   return $stmt->fetch_object('classB', array("A Parameter!"));
  }

 }

 class classB {
  private $param;

  function __construct($param) {
   $this->param = $param;
  }

  public function getParam() {
   return $this->param;
  }

 }

 $classA = new classA();
 echo $classA->createObject()->getParam(); //Returns "A Parameter!"
?>
```

However if I were to try this on a collection of results that same parameter will return '' or null, as indicated by the example below:

```
<?php

 class classA {

  private $dbo;

  function __construct() {
   $this->dbo = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'user', 'pass', 'dbName', 3306);
  }

  public function createObjects() {
   $stmt = $this->dbo->query("SELECT `column` FROM `table` WHERE `column` LIKE '%value%';");
   $myObjects = array();

   foreach($stmt as $result) {
    $myObjects[] = $result->fetch_object("classB", array("A Parameter!"));
   }

   return $myObjects;
  }

 }

 class classB {
  private $param;

  function __construct($param) {
   $this->param = $param;
  }

  public function getParam() {
   return $this->param;
  }

 }

 $classA = new classA();
 $i = 0;
 foreach($classA->createObjects() as $anObject) {
  echo "object[{$i}]:'{$anObject->getParam()}'<br />"; //Returns nothing?
  $i ++;
 }
?>
```

At least, that is how it behaves on my machine.

Now for the questions:
Is this an actual issue with **mysqli_result::fetch_object()** or is it by design?

Either way is there a way of achieving a similar desired result?

Basically I have written a series of classes that right now hinge on this "fault" I have other ways around it, but they are less desirable and I'd rather be challenged and learn something.

Thanks for your time.

**UPDATE:**
It is very possible I have my loop written incorrectly as I just tested with:

```
<?php

 class classA {

  private $dbo;

  function __construct() {
   $this->dbo = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'user', 'pass', 'dbName', 3306);
  }

  public function createObjects() {
   $stmt = $this->dbo->query("SELECT `column` FROM `table` WHERE `column` LIKE '%value%';");
   $myObjects = array();

   if($result = $this->dbo->query("SELECT `column` FROM `table`;")) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_object("classB", array("A Parameter!"))) {
     $myObjects[] = $row;
    }
   }

   return $myObjects;
  }

 }

?>
```

And it appears I get a result, I will test this in greater depth tomorrow.

Comment: you didn't use `extends`

Comment: `extends` in this instance is not required, as I am not extending either class but instead using one to create the other.

Comment: mysqli_result::fetch_object -- mysqli_fetch_object — Returns the current row of a result set as an object.. try look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php)

Comment: Sorry I think I didn't help you at all..

Answer (score 0):

OK turns out I was just being a dork, the loop as previously mentioned above was incorrect.

Here is the fully working example:

```
<?php

 class classA {

  private $dbo;

  function __construct() {
   $this->dbo = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'user', 'pass', 'dbName', 3306);
  }

  public function createObjects() {
   $stmt = $this->dbo->query("SELECT `column` FROM `table` WHERE `column` LIKE '%value%';");
   $myObjects = array();

   if($result = $this->dbo->query("SELECT `column` FROM `table`;")) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_object("classB", array("A Parameter!"))) {
     $myObjects[] = $row;
    }
   }
   return $myObjects;
  }

 }

 class classB {
  private $param;

  function __construct($param) {
   $this->param = $param;
  }

  public function getParam() {
   return $this->param;
  }

 }

 $classA = new classA();
 $i = 0;
 foreach($classA->createObjects() as $anObject) {
  echo "object[{$i}]:'{$anObject->getParam()}'<br />"; //Returns "object[x]:'A Parameter!'<br />"
  $i ++;
 }
?>
```

Again thank you for your time.